# sql server reports iis insufficient permissions

Tags: sql-server-2008, iis

Trying to deploy my sql server iis report from visual studio.

The report server is running on host_B, I am deploying from host_A. I "know" the reason I am getting below error.

My question really is:

How do I get the "reporting services login" page? It has memorized an old username/password which does not have required privileges.

The report is being deployed as User_A which doesn't have sufficient privliges. How do I deploy the report as User_B? Where is this setting from visual studio? It is obviously picking up user_A from somewhere.  Thanks in advance for your help!

Error   1   The permissions granted to user 'DMS\TSReport' are insufficient for performing this operation.      0   0

Answer (score 0):

You should try opening your report solution as a user with sufficient rights to deploy the report to the report server.  Try right-clicking the visual studio icon and choosing "run as" and supply the credentials of the user with rights to the reporting server.

Comment: I am running VS 2010 on Windows 7. There is no "run as", only "run as administrator". And my local admin doesn't exist on the reports server. So still wondering where VS 2010 is picking up that user from. I am sure there is a setting somewhere :(

Comment: no dice, I think I need to get the "reporting services login" prompt to update with correct username/password. Do you have any idea how to get this prompt?